# Formatting string doubts in iphone

Tags: iphone, formatting, nsstring

I have a code that contains verse number and chapter number of the bible. I put this code to `formate chapterno: withverseno:` that is we get 1.2, this means 1 is the chapter number and 2 is the verse number.

my code for this is :

```
cell.chapterAndVerse.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%d",delegate.selectedVerse, indexPath.row+1];
```

chapterAndVerse is the UILabel which holds the verse and chapter number.
I want only verse to display in the UILabel (I want 2 instead of 1.2). How to get this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you could just delete %@. and delegate.selectedVerse. Seems too simple. Have I not understood the question right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.chapterAndVerse.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
```

This will display the verse only.

Comment: i put this but i got all the verses on the bible ie,556077 something

Comment: ohh my god its work for me.i didnt notice your anwesr correctly .thanku very much

Answer (score 1):

You could call :

```
   cell.chapterAndVerse.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", versenumber];
```

But it's a little bit hard to understand in your question why you use an indexPath as you seems to have chapter and verse numbers.

Comment: i put this but i got all the verses on the bible ie,556077 something

Comment: i got undeclared function versenumber

Comment: @ICoder : Can you put in your question the whole code of the function in wich your cann `cell.chapterAndVerse.text` ? I guess it's in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but in that case, I don't understand from where you get the chepter and the verse...

Comment: @ICoder : Ok, but in your pasted code I don't find the `cell.chapterAndVerse.text` call that you talk about in your question.

Comment: i got the anwer ,the gomathi put the right answer,i didnt corectly notice her answer.thanks for your contribution ,thanks very much sir.